# How to select names like I searched SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

I use query to select name with all small letters but he gets all names with small letters and upper letter

this is what I used

```
select Name from _Client where Name = 'mrmiro'
```

I got 2 names with small and upper letters like this

```
mrmiro
MrMiro
```

I just want to select exactly what I searched

Comment: You need to understand collations.  Here is a place to start:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff really helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small matter of changing COLLATE in your query

```
Declare @Table table (Name varchar(25))
Insert Into @Table values 
('mrmiro'),
('MrMiro')

Select * 
 From  @Table 
 Where Name = 'mrmiro' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Returns

```
Name
mrmiro
```